# Migrating data from a MySQL table to PostgreSQL, tinyint to boolean

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am trying to migrate several MySQL tables to Postgresql. They typically have about 20,000 - 50,000 rows.

For most of the tables, I use `mysqldump` to create a SQL file full of `insert` statements, and then `psql` to execute that file in PostgreSQL; this works great.

But, a few of the MySQL tables have "boolean-like" data that's stored as tinyint values (I.e., it contains zeros and ones). In the PostgreSQL tables, that data will be inserted into columns that are actually type `boolean`.

So, when mysqldump creates the `insert` statements, it includes those values as 0 or 1, so psgl complains:

> ERROR:  column "[column_name]" is of type boolean but expression is of
> type integer

I thought about doing a global "find and replace" of all the `0,`  and `1,`  to set them to `false,`  or `true,`  in the sql file, but that won't work, because some of the `0` are actually legitimate `integer` values that need to stay as `0`.

What is the best way to address this? (E.g., is there some way to tell psql that `0` and `1` can be inserted into a `boolean` column as `false` and `true`?

Comment: A possibility, accepting some hand work afterwards, could be to create an extra integer column on the Postgree side, do the import there with the MySql script, then update to the real column within Postgre converting there from integer to boolean, droping the extra column afterwards.

Comment: 0 and 1 are valid boolean values, see the manual. Most likely you have a different value, like -1 or 20, for your boolean. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this post:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46140/have-postgresql-accept-1-and-0-as-true-and-false-for-boolean

Your best option is probably:

If you want to accept 0 and 1 as boolean, create the table with the column defined as smallint with a CHECK (colname >= 0 AND colname <= 1) condition.

After import you can ALTER TABLE to change the type to boolean and provide a USING term to do the type conversion.

Comment: 0 and 1 are valid boolean values, no need to do anything with it. `SELECT CAST(1 AS BOOLEAN);`